# In Entity Framework Core 6 how to use Find() method with part of the composite key?

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I see that `Find` method in EF requires the arguments to be in the same order as in the `HasKey` method.

However, what if I have a composite key let's say `ColA` `ColB` `ColC`. But I only want to find the entities where `ColA=5` and `ColC=6` - without using LINQ, how would I do it in the most efficient (using `Find()`) way?

Comment: You couldn't do this in any EF version, whether Framework or Core. Why do you want to use `Find` instead of `Where`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what if I have a composite key let's say ColA ColB ColC. But I only want to find the entities where ColA=5 and ColC=6

Then you don't want to do what the [`Find()` method is documented to do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.find?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbset-1-find(system-object())):

> Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with the given primary key values is being tracked by the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the database. Otherwise, a query is made to the database for an entity with the given primary key values

You don't have *all* the values that make up the *primary* key (i.e. pointing to a *single* record), so you want to *search*: just build a `Where()` query instead.

> without using LINQ

That is an unnecessary complication.